# Add read permissions to all the directories of a path

Tags: linux, bash, file-permissions, chmod

I want to add (not modify other file permissions) for all the directories in the path written bellow. Something like `chmod -R xx4 /home/mDB/admin/KNUCKLES/dbs/`

The path

```
/home/mDB/admin/KNUCKLES/dbs/
```

I try with this command i found in a forum but doesn't work for me.

```
chmod +r /home/mDB/admin/KNUCKLES/dbs/ -R
```

I only want to change the permissions for all the users not for the file/directory owner or the groups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `chmod +r -R /your/path` should make it. What error do you get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can say:

```
chmod -R o+r /home/mDB/admin/KNUCKLES/dbs/
```

This would give *read* permission recursively to *others*, i.e. not owner/group.

EDIT: As per your comment, it seems that permissions for directories is the issue and not that of files.  You could say:

```
chmod o+rx /home/mDB/{admin,admin/KNUCKLES,admin/KNUCKLES/dbs}
```

Note that since these are directories, you need to set the execute `x` bit on.  Without that, `r` would serve no purpose!

Comment: Sorry, i think my explanation is not so clear. I want to add read permissions for the folders /admin, KNUCKLES and dbs not all the folders inside dbs.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez See the edit above.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to split it up and issue multiple commands.

```
chmod -R xx4 /home/
chmod -R xx4 /home/mDB/
chmod -R xx4 /home/mDB/admin/
chmod -R xx4 /home/mDB/admin/KNUCKLES/
chmod -R xx4 /home/mDB/admin/KNUCKLES/dbs/
```

Someone with more advanced command-line-fu than me may know a shorter way.

Comment: Ok, there is no only a command to do that task. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To set the execute bit only for directories, do the following:

```
chmod -R a+X dir
```

From man chmod:

> execute/search only if the file is  a  directory or  already  has 
>   execute permission for some user (X)

Answer from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39761/execute-bit-on-directories-but-not-files